# Ionic 7 How to calculate hash SHA-256 from a photo captured by the camera

Tags: android, ionic-framework, photo, checksum

I have a project in Ionic 7 and i need to calculate hash SHA-256 from a photo captured by the camera.

I already have the captured image and i have the url to display it.

However, I can't find any function that allows me to calculate the SHA-256 hash of the file that contains the captured image.

I hope you can help me.

I will need to know if exists a way to calculate or get hash SHA-256 after take the photo with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebCrypto API to calculate the SHA-256 hash.

```
window.crypto.subtle.digest(
  {
    name: "SHA-256",
  },
  imageFileData // The image file data you want to calculate a hash for as an ArrayBuffer
)
.then(function(hash) {
  // convert the hash to byte array
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hash));                     
  // convert bytes to hex string
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); 
  // use the hashHex string for comparison
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found this solution to my problem:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CryptoService {
  constructor(
    
  ) { }

 getHash256(imagePath:string){
    this.toDataURL(imagePath).then(result=>{
      const imagenBase64=result;
      var encryptedData = crypto.SHA256(arrayBufferToWordArray(imagenBase64));//<-encryptedData contents the value of SHA-256 hash
      return encryptedData.toString();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    return false;
  }

  
  toDataURL = async (url:string) => {
    var res = await fetch(url);
    var blob = await res.blob();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        resolve(reader.result);
      }, false);
      
      reader.onerror = () => {
        return reject(this);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
  }
}

function arrayBufferToWordArray(fileResult:any) {
  var i8a = new Uint8Array(fileResult);
  var byteArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
    byteArray.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
  }
  return crypto.lib.WordArray.create(byteArray, i8a.length);
}
```

And to call the function:

```
let hashImage=getHash256(string_with_path_of_image);
```